# Error de compatibilidad en Internet Explorer 11

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

Estoy usando esta version de IE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una aplicación Web de un inventario y todo lo que este conlleva...Mi problema es que en el navegador Chrome, todo se ve y funciona perfectamente pero en el navegador de IE v11 no funciona y no se ve nada.

Como se puede ver desde un inicio ya muestra información de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el navegador de IE, y como se puede ver no muestra los datos como la primera imagen. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas al cambiar de opción en el menu lateral, muestra el siguiente error.

> SCRIPT5009: 'init' is undefined.
>
> Este init lo tengo en el `<body onload="init()">`

Cuando doy clic en `+Add iTEM` donde se abre un modal para registrar, sucede lo siguiente...

> SCRIPT5009: 'openModalAdd' is undefined.
>
> Ese error lleva a la siguiente linea en el html `<button type="button"
>   class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" style="font-size: 12pt; width:250%;
>   height:33px;" onclick="openModalAdd()">+ Add Item</button>`

Para el desarrollo de esta App Web, se utilizo lo siguiente:

```
HTML.
CSS.
JS.
BOOTSTRAP.
APIS (PHP).
```

He leído la documentación de compatibilidad, pero no encuentro solución alguna.

Alguien podría apoyarme?

Comment: que versión de boostrap usas?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7

Tengo estos dos archivos:  `bootstrap.min` y `bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir este meta en la sección del `<head> </head>` para hacerlo compatible con Internet Explore 11 y Internet Explore Edge

`<meta http-equiv = contenido "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE = edge">`

Pero lo mejor seria que uses el navegador Edge, si usaras Internet Explore.

Comment: internet explorer no posee ninguna opción para actualizarse a Edge, EDGE se instala como otro navegador aparte de Internet Explorer

Comment: No funciona, ya he intentado con otros metas, pero igual, no muestra y marca errores al dar clic en el boton antes mencionado.

Comment: Y si usas Edge, porque Internet Explorer 11, publicado en octubre de 2013, fue la última versión de Internet Explorer publicada por Microsoft. Con esta versión Microsoft culminó el esfuerzo de modernización y adaptación a las recomendaciones del W3C que había empezado en 2006 con Internet Explorer 7. Pero con esta versión, Microsoft decidió empezar de cero y abandonó el desarrollo de Internet Explorer. Su sucesor fue Microsoft Edge, que está basado en un motor nuevo, aunque su numeración ha continuado la numeración de Internet Explorer (12, 13, etc.).

Comment: Realmente necesito que función en esa version Internet Explorer v.11, entiendo lo que me comentas y tu recomendación, pero realmente no hay nada que se pueda hacer en este caso?

Comment: ok, que versión de jquery estas usando?

Comment: Tengo estos 2 archivos:

`jquery-2.1.1` , `jquery-3.1.1.min`

Comment: bueno no quiero desalentarte, pero Internet explore 11 solo soporta jquery 1.x, tendrías que usar que usar algunos parches.

Comment: podrías orientarme en como hacer eso,de donde lo descargo? como aplicarlo?...etc